# Does Korra have an Avatar tattoo?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

Once her bending was restored to her by the spirit of Aang, did Korra get an Avatar tattoo, and if so, what, and where was it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**No. She had no reason to, so it is unlikely that she would.**

The tattoos are a feature solely associated with the Air Nomad tribes. Because they are made across the body's chi pathways, they glow when an Air Nomad Avatar focuses his Chi into the Avatar state. Korra is from the Water Tribes, so she would not have traditional Air Nomad tattoos to begin with, and no reason to have them done.

Comment: Once she masters the air element, is she not an Airbender?

Comment: @MajorStackings That still doesn't make her an Air Nomad. Of the previous Avatars, only Air Nomads had the tattoos. See [the scene from last episode where previous Avatars were shown](http://i29.photobucket.com/albums/c251/Tauriel/korra_avatars.jpg).

Comment: @MajorStackings svick is right. I said the tattoos are an Airbender thing, but its more accurate to say they are an Air Nomad thing. The terms were fairly interchangeable until *Legend of Korra*.